Firestore Security Rules: (minimal) code that doesn't work against these rules
I'm working on setting up Firestore security rules, but I'm facing an issue where my custom function getUserOrganization() doesn't seem to return the correct value when used in matching conditions. Specifically, the function is supposed to return the organization ID of the authenticated user, but the matching condition doesn't seem to work as expected.

I have the following security rules to restrict access to documents in the Organisations collection based on the user's organization:

rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /Organisations/{orgId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserOrganization() == orgId;
      
      match /{subcollection=**}/{docId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserOrganization() == orgId;
      }
    }
  }

  // Function to get the user's organization from their document
  function getUserOrganization() {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organisation.id;
  }
}

Issue
When I try to access an organization document using the rule:
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserOrganization() == orgId;

It throws a permission error. However, if I hardcode the organization ID like this:
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && "Sjc7mG12B0LPPe5bcJOf" == orgId;

The rule works as expected, and access is granted.
This leads me to believe that the getUserOrganization() function might not be returning the correct value or might be returning a value in a different format (e.g., different data type, string encoding, etc.).
What I've Tried:

Verified that the organization ID in the user's document is correctly set and matches the organization document ID.
Confirmed that the getUserOrganization() function is correctly fetching the organization ID from the user's document.

Additional Information:

The getUserOrganization() function is supposed to return the organization ID from the user's document in the Users collection.
The organisations.id field in the Users document is a string, and it matches the ID of documents in the Organisations collection.

Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

in User Document I have map object for user organisation
  "organisation": {
    "id": "org123",
    "name": "My Organization"
  },
  "user_role": {
    "role": "advertiser"
  }
}


Security rules don't do anyting on their own, but only become active when you execute code against them. Can you edit your question to include the (minimal) code that doesn't work against these rules?

From what I understand or from my past experience with Firebase security rules, I think they shouldn't return anything other than boolean values.
So, can you try doing this instead:
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    match /Users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
    
    match /Organisations/{orgId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserOrganization(orgId);
      
      match /{subcollection=**}/{docId} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && getUserOrganization(orgId);
      }
    }
  }

  // Function to get the user's organization from their document
  function getUserOrganization(orgId) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.organisation.id == orgId;
  }
}

In this, you're directly passing the orgId as an argument, comparing it inside the function and returning the resulting boolean.
Let me know if that works :)

I tried I think this should work but when deeply debug that so I find that my this line of code is returning nothing(unable to understand what it return)
exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)); this is false
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data != null and get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data == null all those are false I tried that return true so it work I thing anything is here that is missing or mismatch I dabble check spalling it is correct. See Code.
